# How to dynamically populate new page with variable set on last page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP and am trying to build my a website to display information on TV shows stored in a MySQL DB. I've currently got a webpage that will create a table to display the information in the DB, however I'd like each row to link to a dynamically populated page with more info on each show (also pulling from the DB). My question is how do I get the site to know which link has been clicked and then save that as a variable so it can then be recalled on a new to populate the correct information?

I'm currently using this to populate the page.

```
<!--Populate page with data from SQL-->
            <?php
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "media_server";

                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

                $sql = "SELECT show_title, show_desc, thumbnail_path FROM tv_shows WHERE status = 'Y'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "<table><tr><th></th><th></th></tr>";
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td> 
                                <img src='../images/thumbnails/tv/".$row["thumbnail_path"]."'>
                            </td>

                            <td class='td_title'> 
                                <a href='#' onclick='show_var_set();'>".$row["show_title"]."</a>
                            </td>

                            <td class='td_desc'>".$row["show_desc"]."</td>
                        </tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                } else {
                    echo "Error - 0 results were returned my the database. Please try again.";
                }
                $conn->close();
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to change your href links to point to this page and pass a GET variable you can retreive.  The added bonus to this approach is you could bookmark a particular show and come back to that page, since the bookmark will include that GET variable.

So you could change your links to something like this:

```
echo '<a href="thispage.php?show=', $row['show_title'], '">', $row['show_title'],'</a>';
```

Then you'd retrieve that variable by testing for, then reading the GET variable and performing a db query to populate the page with that show's data.

Here's how you'd test for and retreive that variable:

```
if (isset($_GET['show']))
{
    $show = $_GET['show'];
    // Perform database lookup using $show
}
```

Remember to *never* put user input directly into a query, but use prepared statements and bind the user data to avoid the risk of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass values from page to page but one is to use session variables:

```
//Include this at the top of your php scripts that use session variables
session_start();

$_SESSION['your_variable_name_here'] = value_you_want_to_store;
```

Then on the page you would like to access this use:

```
$someVariable = $_SESSION['your_variable_name_here'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the SQL to return the `show_id`,

```
$sql = "SELECT show_id, show_title, show_desc, thumbnail_path FROM tv_shows WHERE status = 'Y'";
```

and use that as a parameter to the `show_var_set()` function.

```
    <a href='#' onclick='show_var_set(".$row["show_id"].");'>".$row["show_title"]."</a>
```

The `show_var_set()` function can then use that parameter to get the details for that show from the database.